# Convert comma separated string into individual rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL variables `@item1` and `@item2`, which have values `"abc,def"` , `"ghi,jkl"` respectively.

And I have a table like this:

```
--------------------
Id | item1 | item2 |
--------------------
```

The result I want is:

```
--------------------
Id | item1 | item2 |
--------------------
1  | abc   | ghi   |
--------------------
2  | def   | jkl   |
--------------------
```

I have tried to use the `splitstring` function in SQL Server, but thats not working in this scenario.

What I have tried

```
Insert into table (item1,item2)
(Select * from Splitstring (@item1,',')),
(Select * from Splitstring (@item2, ','))
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Yup updated the question

Comment: Thats not a SQL Server function unless you misspelled it? Nor can you combine 2 selects like that - looks like you might want union, but hard to tell.

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if you are not sure of the syntax or how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server 2016, a JSON-based approach is a possible option. The idea is to transform the input text values into a valid JSON array (`abc,def` into `["abc","def"]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` column holds the 0-based index of each item from the parsed array.

```
DECLARE @item1 varchar(max) = 'abc,def'
DECLARE @item2 varchar(max) = 'ghi,jkl'

INSERT INTO [Table] (item1, item2)
SELECT j1.[value], j2.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@item1, ',', '","'), '"]')) j1
FULL OUTER JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@item2, ',', '","'), '"]')) j2 
   ON j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Note, that starting from SQL Server 2022, you may use `SRING_SPLIT()` with the `enable_ordinal` parameter to get the same results:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (item1, item2)
SELECT s1.[value], s2.[value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@item1, ',', 1) s1
FULL OUTER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@item1, ',', 1) s2 
   ON s1.[ordinal] = s2.[ordinal]
```